# Unresolved external symbol(LNK2019)

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ . I am trying to develop a C++ application but there is one error that is keep bothering me.

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)"

I think I have referenced all of my functions in another file

**This is the code of my cpp file:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"




int console::main()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "-----------ABC Homestay Management System-----------" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

system("color 0f");
cout << "Please enter your choice" << endl;
cout << "1.Upload listings" << endl;
cout << "2.Find listings" << endl;
cout << "3.View listings" << endl;
cout << "4.Exit" << endl;

int choice;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    //renter();
    break;
case 2:
    //finder();
    break;
case 3:
    //listings();
    break;
case 4:
    exit(0);
    break;
case 8:
    //staff();//secret key -> 8 for staff
    break;
}

    system("pause");
main();
return 0;
 }

    void console::finder() {
        system("cls");
            cout << "test" << endl; 

    }
```

**This is the "stdafx.h" header file that I have referenced in the cpp file :**

```
    #pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <regex>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;



class console {

public:
    console() {}
    ~console() {}
    int main();
    void renter();
    void finder();
    void listings();
    void staff();



};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your program doesn't have a `main` function which is the entry point of a C++ program. The `console::main()` function cannot serve for this purpose, BTW you don't have any variable of type `console` at all in your program, therefore you never can call any of the methods of the `console` class. I think you should start reading your C++ text book from the beginning.

You want this:

```
...
int main()
{
  console myconsole;
  myconsole.main();
}
```

and BTW, this is fishy:

```
system("pause");
main();          // you probably want to remove this
return 0;
```

you probably want a loop here.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, entry point of program is `main` function and it has to be outside of any class. In your code, you declared `int main()` inside `console` class.

Answer (score 1):

All c++ programs must have an entry function called main that is not part of any class.

Correct routine would be a main function that creates your object that represents the bulk of your program and then run that's main function:

```
int main()
{
  console myconsole;
  myconsole.main();
}
```

Comment: an object that "represents the bulk of your program" ? I guess it is just the wording that disturbs me a bit, but imho representing the bulk of a program is far too much to put in a single class, a class should be responsible for only one thing

Comment: For example if you were making a game, it's common form to have a "Game" class that contains references to your higher level manager classes and contains a Game.Run function. and then related program functions for exiting etc. Probably better to call it a manager class or a program management class. It's your entry point in relation to the type of program you're making.